# Last modified date using REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I want to retrieve the last modified date of list items from custom lists in a site in SharePoint and place it in a table using REST API

Comment: Can you provide any additional details? Do you just want to retrieve a dataset of each item in a single custom list along with the Modified Date of each? Are you trying to aggregate from multiple lists? Also, please provide any code you've tried - assumign you're using JS, the AJAX call to retrieve the data, script to iterate through the results & create a table, etc.

Answer (score 1):

TTy the REST API END POINT: {yourservername}/{sitecollection}/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('listname')/Items?$select=Modified;